# How do I add audio to my stream with ffmpeg -i hw:0,2 does not work

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, streaming

Im trying to stream my desktop with audio to icecast but Im getting this error

```
[alsa @ 0x561796555320] ALSA buffer xrun.
```

here is my command

```
ffmpeg -video_size 1680x1050 -framerate 25 -f x11grab -i :0.0 -f alsa -sample_rate 48000 -channels 2 -i hw:0,2 -f webm -r 25 -s 1280x800 -cluster_size_limit 2M -cluster_time_limit 5100 -content_type video/webm -c:v libvpx -b:v 1M -crf 30 -g 125  -deadline good -threads 4 icecast://source:hackme@localhost:8000/live.webm
```

here is my list of audo devices, I dont know how to select right one, I wont audio from my rear audio where I have my 2.1 audio setup

```
arecord -L

default
    Playback/recording through the PulseAudio sound server
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
pulse
    PulseAudio Sound Server
sysdefault:CARD=Intel
    HDA Intel, ALC883 Analog
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, ALC883 Analog
    Front speakers
dmix:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, ALC883 Analog
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=Intel,DEV=2
    HDA Intel, ALC883 Alt Analog
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, ALC883 Analog
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=Intel,DEV=2
    HDA Intel, ALC883 Alt Analog
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, ALC883 Analog
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=Intel,DEV=2
    HDA Intel, ALC883 Alt Analog
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
    HDA Intel, ALC883 Analog
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=Intel,DEV=2
    HDA Intel, ALC883 Alt Analog
    Hardware device with all software conversions
```

Comment: can you try this `... -i hw:CARD=Intel,DEV=2 ...`?

Comment: @БаярГончикжапов still no audio

Comment: What can I say. Give up and use pulseaudio: `-f pulse -i 0`

Comment: @БаярГончикжапов it doesn't work either

Comment: in my case: `hw:CARD=PCH,DEV=0` is microphone input, `hw:CARD=PCH,DEV=2`, possible, is line input. I don't have device to plug in to `line-in`, but microphone works normal `arecord /tmp/out.wav`. Maybe, you have to configure `alsamixer`. About pulse. Can you look to output from `pacmd list-sources` to get number of your audio input, maybe `-f pulse -i 1`